# Need to understand gulp

Tags: gulp

I am getting object expected gulp error, but found solutions as rename file to gulfile.js

1. Need to understand every project has only one gulp file thats gulpfile.js? If i need to define more than one then how to and what will be the file name.
2. My requirement is to concatenate more than one less(convert to css) & js file into one and then apply it to index.html
3. I am using express to create gulp project structure. is this standard way? if no then how do i?
4. Everytime I create gulp skeleton, do i need to install all packages again for every project?

Any references from where can learn gulp from basic.

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1a) Yes, it has to be called gulpfile.js

1b) If you search Stack Overflow and Google for "multiple gulpfiles" you'll get a lot of solutions. But just so you know, it's better to start with just one gulpfile - it can be hard to get multiple gulpfiles working correctly, and using just one will help you learn gulp.

2. You'll need to use [gulp-less](https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less) and [gulp-concat](https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat) to turn multiple LESS files into one CSS file, and gulp-concat again to turn multiple js files into one.
3. You can use express, but you don't have to do. It depends what you're doing, and we have no idea what you're doing.
4. Not sure what you mean by "gulp skeleton". If you mean "Do I need to run `npm install` for every new project, yes you do.
5. Google "learn gulp"
6. If an image could just be text, it's better to just include the text.